# An integer is required?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting my code to work from my `Wtime` function but after I set the `waitTime` for my `Wtime`, it doesn't translate over to my `main` function. When I press my button for my LED to work I get:

```
  time.sleep(waitTime)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type function)
```

This is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

#leds
rled = 16
yled = 6

#btns
btnOnVal = 12
btnOffVal = 18

#ldr
ltSense = 21


GPIO.setup(rled, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(yled, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setup(btnOnVal, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(btnOffVal, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

GPIO.setup(ltSense, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

def Wtime():
    try:
        waitTime = float(input("Please enter a wait time for flashing lights(1 - 10 secs):"))

        while (waitTime < 0 or waitTime > 10):
            waitTime = float(input("Please enter a wait time for flashing lights(1 - 10 secs):"))
    except:
        print("Not Integer Value")

    return waitTime

def rblink(waitTime):
    GPIO.output(rled, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(waitTime)
    GPIO.output(rled, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(waitTime)

def yblink(waitTime):
    GPIO.output(yled, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(waitTime)
    GPIO.output(yled, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(waitTime)

def main(waitTime):
    while (GPIO.input(ltSense) == 1):
        if (GPIO.input(btnOnVal) == False):
            for i in range(0,10,1):
                rblink(waitTime)

        if (GPIO.input(btnOffVal) == False):
            for i in range(0,10,1):
               yblink(waitTime)

#function call
Wtime()
main(yblink)
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: The error is telling you that your parameter is wrong.  What do you think your parameter (`waitTime`) is? Why?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the result of `wTime()` into `main()`:

```
main(Wtime())
```

---

*Also, you should ideally start the names of functions with lowercase characters as the standard is uppercase characters for classes.*